# Two Excel macros seem to conflict and prevent each other from working

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to write some macros to a cross-departmental spreadsheet, which when I press a command button will essentially "archive" a row of work. I also have one which is meant to auto-capitalise a column when people type in it. See below:

This is the Archive macro:

```
Sub Archive()


If MsgBox("Do you want to archive the selected row?" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Row should only be archived after x has passed.", vbYesNo, "Archive") = vbNo Then Exit Sub

For Each WSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If WSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
            If WSheet.FilterMode Then
                WSheet.ShowAllData
            End If
        End If
        For Each DTable In WSheet.ListObjects
            If DTable.ShowAutoFilter Then
                DTable.Range.AutoFilter
                DTable.Range.AutoFilter
            End If
        Next DTable
    Next WSheet

'Declare variables
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long

'Set variables
    Set sht1 = Sheets("xDepartment")
    Set sht2 = Sheets("Archive")

'Select Entire Row
    Selection.EntireRow.Select

'Move row to destination sheet & Delete source row
    lastRow = sht2.Range("A" & sht2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With Selection
        .Copy Destination:=sht2.Range("A" & lastRow + 1)
        .EntireRow.Delete
    End With

End Sub
```

The autocapitalisation macro is attached to the specific sheet? (i.e., it's attached when right-clicking on "xDepartment" and selecting "View code" - not sure if that has something to do with it?). There's also a macro on this sheet which calculates the date that data in a certain cell is changed:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A1 As Range
    Set A1 = Range("O:O,Q:Q,T:T,W:W")
    If Not Intersect(Target, A1) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.Value = UCase(Target.Value)
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

    Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim xOffsetColumn As Integer
Set WorkRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("O:O, Q:Q"), Target)
xOffsetColumn = 1
If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each Rng In WorkRng
        If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = Now
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
        Else
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).ClearContents
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

End Sub
```

The error that comes up is "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch". Do you know why this might be happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you see what line the type mismatch is on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your First line in the Archive macro put

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
On error goto Whoops
```

Then just above your End Sub for that macro put

```
 Whoops:
 Application.EnableEvents = True
```

This will turn off the other macro while your archive is running

Answer (score 1):

Your code to move the row from xDepartment worksheet to Archive worksheet includes the line,

```
Selection.EntireRow.Select
```

This makes the xDepartment worksheet active. The code to actually move the row and remove the original does nothing to change the xDepartment as the ActiveSheet.

```
With Selection
    .Copy Destination:=sht2.Range("A" & lastRow + 1)
    .EntireRow.Delete
End With
```

In your worksheet_change, you have,

```
Set WorkRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("O:O, Q:Q"), Target)
```

So your Archive worksheet's Worksheet_Change is going to try to work on the xDepartment worksheet.

But you delete the row so it no longer exists; hen ce:

> Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

Set your WorkRng with,

```
    Set WorkRng = Intersect(Range("O:O, Q:Q"), Target)
```

It is in a private sub procedure on the Archive's private code sheet so there is no need to specify a parent worksheet unless you specifically want to work on another worksheet.

Avoid the use of ActiveSheet, Select, Selection and Activate whenever possible and **never** use them in a worksheet's private code sheet to refer to that worksheet.